# webSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed: when i try to connect socket io client to server

Tags: node.js, next.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a problem about connecting websocket from Next.js clientside to a node js server side..

the error is : `webSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:`

I'm working on it since yesterday but still can't connect to serverside, and I have no idea why it's happening, the node js runs on port 8000 and Next js runs on 3001.

and here is my codes :

Node js

```
import http from "http";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: ["*"],
  },
});

....

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(socket);
  console.log("a user connected");
});

app.listen(PORT, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("Server is running on PORT", PORT);
  }
});
```

and here is Next js codes :

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8000", {
  transports: ["websocket"],
});

const IndexPage = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Investment spot</title>
      </Head>
      <Navbar />

      <h1 className="text-center   my-5" style={{ color: "#FFBA00" }}>
        The winners
      </h1>

      <Container fluid className="mt-5">
        <Row>
          <Col xs={6}>
            <Winners data={props.data} />
          </Col>
          <Col xs={6} className="d-flex align-items-start mb-5">
            <Prizes data={props.image} />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default IndexPage;
```

I tried to solve with the code provided in other questions in stack overflow and chatGPT, but didn't work to me.

Answer (score 0):

the way how you set up the server is not correct. [check the npm docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io)

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', () => { /* … */ });
server.listen(3000);
```

you are starting the express app

```
app.listen(PORT, (err) => {}
```

It should be

```
server.listen(PORT)
```

also you might need to add cors policy to express

```
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
// always register middlewares first
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: i followed all steps in npm docs, but i didn't put all codes in here just to make it more readable, of course i added CORS policy..

and here is no problem with it, 
`app.listen(PORT, (err) => {}`
because im using it for years.

i solved the problem, i will provide the source code in next comment.

thank you.